# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

```
MN = '1+2+3+2*(2*2)'
MN = str (MN)
print (MN)
MN = unicode(MN, 'utf-8 ')
s2 = list (MN)
print (s2)

#int N,j,i,L,S,E,ds;
N = int(0);j = int(0);i = int(0);L = int(0);S = int(0);
E = int(0);ds = int(0);
#int x1p,x2p,Rp=0;
x1p = float(0);x2p = float(0);Rp =float(0)
Rp=0
#float Rc = 0,Rs=0,Rr=0,x1c,x2c,x1s,x2s,x1r,x2r,y,MR=0;
Rc = 0;Rs=0;Rr=0;MR=0;
Rc = float(0);Rs = float(0);Rr = float(0);MR = float(0);
x1c = float(0);x2c = float(0);x1s = float(0);x2s = float(0);
x1r = float(0);x2r = float(0);y = float(0);
L=str (MN);
print (L)
i=0
#for i in i<len(L)-1, ++i :
for i in range(len(L)):
    if (MN[i]=='('):
        S=i;
        i=0
        for i in range(len(L)):
            #for i in i<L,++i:
            if (MN[i]==')'):
                E=i;
print (S, E)
print (s2[S])

#umnojenie
i=0
#S = int (S)
#for i in i<ds, ++i:
for i in xrange(S,E):
    print(S, E)
    if (s2[i]=='*'):
        a = i-1
        b = i+1
        print (a,b)
        x1p= map(int,s2[a])
        x2p= map(int,s2[b])
        #x1p=s2[a]
        #x2p=s2[b]
        print ("zdesa1",x1p);
        print ("zdesa2",x2p);
        Rp=(x1p[0])*(x2p[0])
        print("\npro=%d",Rp)

#delenie
i=S
#for i in i<ds,++i:
for i in range(E):
    if (s2[i]=='/'):
        a = i-1
        b = i+1
        x1c=map(int,s2[a])
        x2c=map(int,s2[b])
        if (Rp!=0):
            if (x1c==x2p):
                x1c=Rp
            if (x2c==x1p):
                x2c=Rp
        print("\nX1 %d",x1c);
        print ("\nX2 %d",x2c);
        Rc=(x1c[0])/(x2c[0])
        print("\ncha=%f",Rc)
#summa
i=S
#for i in i<ds,++i:
for i in range(E):
    if (s2[i]=='+'):
        a = i-1
        b = i+1
        x1r=map(int,s2[a])
        x2r=map(int,s2[b])
        if (Rp!=0):
            if (x1r==x2p):
                x1r=Rp;
            if (x2r==x1p):
                x2r=Rp;
        if (Rc!=0):
            if (x1r==x2c):
                x1r=Rc;
            if (x2r==x1c):
                x2r=Rc;
        if (Rr!=0):
            if (x1r==x2s):
                x1r=Rr;
            if (x2r==x1s):
                x2r=Rr;
        print ("\nX1 %f",x1r);
        print ("\nX2 %f",x2r);
        Rs=(x1r[0])+(x2r[0]);
        print("\nraz=%f",Rr);

#raznost
i=S
#for i in i<ds,++i:
for i in range(E):
    if (s2[i]=='-'):
        a = i-1
        b = i+1
        x1r=map(int,s2[a])
        x2r=map(int,s2[b])
        if (Rp!=0):
            if (x1r==x2p):
                x1r=Rp;
            if (x2r==x1p):
                x2r=Rp;
        if (Rc!=0):
            if (x1r==x2c):
                x1r=Rc;
            if (x2r==x1c):
                x2r=Rc;
        if (Rs!=0):
            if (x1r==x2s):
                x1r=Rs;
            if (x2r==x1s):
                x2r=Rs;
        print ("\nX1 %f",x1r);
        print ("\nX2 %f",x2r);
        Rr=(x1r[0])-(x2r[0]);
        print("\nraz=%f",Rr);

if (Rp!=0):
    y=Rp;  #itog
if (Rc!=0):
    y=Rc;
if (Rs!=0):
    y=Rs;
if (Rr!=0):
    y=Rr;

#if (MN[E+1]=='*'): 
if (MN[E]=='*'):
    MR=y*(MN[E]);
#if (MN[E+1]=='/'):
if (MN[E]=='/'):
    MR=y/(MN[E]);
#if (MN[E+1]=='+'):
if (MN[E]=='+'):
    MR=y+(MN[E]);
#if (MN[E+1]=='-'):
if (MN[E]=='-'):
    MR=y-(MN[E]);
print("rezultat",MR);
```

Не могу понять. Все считает правильно, окромя сложения, почему-то он думает, что обект имеет что-то, и думает, что это надо сложить, даже если сложения не предвидится. 
Выводит ошибку Rs=(x1r[0])+(x2r[0]); TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: Чувак, ты делаешь это просто-напросто неправильно. Как я понял, ты хочешь написать вычислитель. Во-первых, зачем ты декларируешь переменные, значения которых вообще не используются, а просто перезаписываются? Зачем писать N=int(0) вместо N=0? Да и вообще зачем тебе объявлять, что N=0, если ты этот самый 0 не используешь? Почему у тебя проверка на скобки "решается" одним вложенным циклом?Твой метод не справится с выражением типа (2+(3-(2-4/2))-5/2).
Зачем ты делашь проверку знака, если можно провести сверку по ключу словаря? В общем, ты используешь синтаксис питона, но по факту пишешь на си.

Comment: [пример вычисления арифметического выражения на Питоне](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4279). Я могу ответь на вопросы по коду, если что-то не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Строку 95

```
Rr=(x1r[0])-(x2r[0]);
```

замени на

```
if type(x1r) == int and type(x2r) == int:
    Rs=(x1r)+(x2r);
elif type(x1r) == int and type(x2r) != int:
    Rs=(x1r)+(x2r[0]);
elif type(x1r) != int and type(x2r) == int:
    Rs=(x1r[0])+(x2r);
else:
    Rs=(x1r[0])+(x2r[0]);
```

Отработает, если хочешь по-другому написать, пожалуйста, но я не особо хочу вникать в расчет.